# Mysql: replace leading zeroes inside text

Tags: mysql, regex, replace

I wish to replace cca 3 500 000 values in Mysql Table. Each value is string in the form of `AB00123012` and I wish to remove leading zeroes after letters - i.e. get `AB123012` (zeroes inside number should be kept).
The value has always exactly 10 characters.

Since Mysql does not allow replace by regex, I have used following function:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION fn_RawRingNumber (rn CHAR(10))
RETURNS CHAR(10) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE newrn CHAR(10);
    DECLARE pos INT(8);
    DECLARE letters CHAR(2);
    DECLARE nr CHAR(8);

    IF (CHAR_LENGTH(rn) = 10) THEN
        SET pos = (SELECT POSITION('0' IN rn));
        SET letters = (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(rn, '0', 1));
        SET nr = (SELECT TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM SUBSTRING(rn,pos)));
        SET newrn = (SELECT CONCAT(letters, nr));
    ELSE
        SET newrn = rn;
    END IF;

    RETURN newrn;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

While this works, it is rather slow and I am wondering, if there is not a better way to do this?

Comment: Definitely. The better way is not to do this at all. What you have is a data presentation issue. These look like hex numbers. Just format them at display time. Well supported in almost any language and almost 0 cost.

Comment: @e4c5 Actually I have a good reason to do that - the data are imported from old source and values `A123` and `A000000123` are the same thing. Now, when I search the database I have to always use `select * from Items where Code = 'A123' or Code = 'A000000123'`, which slows the queries significantly.

Comment: So these are not hex codes that you have?

Comment: There is always 2 letters at start? or may be also something like this: `ABC09..` ?

Comment: @OtoShavadze There is one of two letters at the beginning, then leading zeroes and then number (which might include 0). Leading zeroes pad the string, so i has 10 characters. There might be dot character instead of on of the letters. (`.E00086425`)

Comment: @e4c5 These are some identification codes, but not hex codes. Letters can be taken from whole englisg alphabeth.

Comment: Extract the left most 2 characters cast the right remaining characters to int (to drop leading zeros) and then cast back to character and then concat() them back together.  The assumption is always that the first two characters are irrelevant and the right most would always be numeric. `Update Table Set FieldName = concat(LEFT(FieldName,2),cast(cast(mid(FieldName,3,8) as int) as Varchar(8))`

Comment: Note your comment about A123 and A000000123 being roughly the same shows an example in your data where the first two characters are not letters and one would contain a leading zero... so my comment may not be valid.  My comment assumes 1st two characters are always needed values.

Comment: Are there any rules (format) for composition of your values (eg. '456A002' is a value allowed and should it become '456A2'?)

Comment: The task is better done with a real programming language, not SQL.  Or, if you have MariaDB, use its `regexp_replace()` function.

Comment: @etsa the code composes always from type (one or two letters) and number. The number is preceded by leading zeroes, so that the length of the whole string is 10 characters

Comment: did you try my suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford to take your site offline for a few minutes, the fastest way would be to dump, process and re import. Since the current operation makes queries/inserts on that table pretty slow, so you are probably better off with a dump/process/import anyway.

### Step 1 dump.

[SELECT INTO OUTFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html) is your friend here

### Step 2 process

Use your favourite programming language or if you are lucky to be on linux, something like `sed` or even `cut`. If you need help with the regex post a comment.

### Step 3 reimport

After clearing out the table. Do a LOAD DATA INFILE.

these three steps should all be reasonably quick. Specially if you have a n index on that column.

Comment: Thanks for tip, but I would rather do it all in mysql (i have, actualy - run it over night using function in my question and it was done in 10 minutes). I was just wandering, whether there is more elegant mysql way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Note: I not tested this with many rows and don't know how this is efficient.

Also, if this is fast, please before using this, **think all possible variations, which may occurs with your string**, may be I missed some variants, not sure 100%.

```
select  case
    when INSTR(col, '0') = 2 then concat(  substr(col, 1, 1), substr(col, 2) * 1)
    when INSTR(col, '0') = 3 and substr(col, 2, 1) not in('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9') then concat(  substr(col, 1, 2), substr(col, 3) * 1)
    else col
end
from (
    select 'AB00123012' as col union all
    select 'A010000123' as col union all
    select 'A1000000124' as col union all
    select 'A0000000124' as col union all
    select '.E00086425' as col
) t
```